# How to add a count function in a random variable

Tags: python

Just wondering how I can count the number of an objects that are left when randomly picked

I have included my code before but am struggling with what function to use.

```
import random
biscuits = []

biscuits.extend(['Monte Carlo']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Shortbread Cream']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Delta Cream']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Kingston']*5) 

print('\nASSORTED CREAMS\n')

choice = random.randint(0,len(biscuits)-1)
remaining = biscuits.count('')
print('Your biscuit is : ', biscuits[choice])
print('Your remaining number of biscuits are : ', remaining)
del biscuits[choice]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pop` is a function that will remove the element from the array , but will return the value

```
import random
biscuits = []

biscuits.extend(['Monte Carlo']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Shortbread Cream']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Delta Cream']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Kingston']*5) 

print('\nASSORTED CREAMS\n')

choice = random.randint(0,len(biscuits)-1)
print('Your biscuit is : ', biscuits.pop(choice))
print('Your remaining number of biscuits are : ', len(biscuts))
```

Here is The output:

```
ASSORTED CREAMS

Your biscuit is :  Kingston
Your remaining number of biscuits are :  24
```

Answer (score 0):

You choose `choice` biscuits (the value of choice is int)

So the number of remaining biscuits is - `len(biscuits)-choice`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
biscuits = []

biscuits.extend(['Monte Carlo']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Shortbread Cream']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Delta Cream']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Kingston']*5) 

print('\nASSORTED CREAMS\n')

choice = random.randint(0,len(biscuits)-1)
biscuits.pop(choice) ## Removes the biscuits from the list
remaining = len(biscuits) ## Gets the amount of biscuits in the list
print('Your biscuit is : ', biscuits[choice])
print('Your remaining number of biscuits are : ', remaining)
del biscuits[choice]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like that.

```
    import random
biscuits = []

biscuits.extend(['Monte Carlo']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Shortbread Cream']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Delta Cream']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Kingston']*5) 

print('\nASSORTED CREAMS\n')
choice = random.randint(0,len(biscuits)-1)
print('Your biscuit is : ', biscuits[choice])
del biscuits[choice]
remaining = len(biscuits)
print('Your remaining number of biscuits are : ', remaining)
```

First delete the item, then count the array

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to count each time a choice has been removed.

Also, the value of `remaining` might be incorrect since it counting all occurrences `''` rather than the actual choice made.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you should be using is `yourlist.pop`

```
import random
biscuits = []

biscuits.extend(['Monte Carlo']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Shortbread Cream']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Delta Cream']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Kingston']*5)

print('\nASSORTED CREAMS\n')

print('Number of biscuits:', len(biscuits))
choice = random.randint(0, len(biscuits)-1)
chosenbiscuit = biscuits.pop(choice)
remaining = len(biscuits)
print('Your biscuit is : ', chosenbiscuit)
print('Your remaining number of biscuits are : ', remaining)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `dict` as data container, where value will be amount of each item left.

```py
from random import choices

biscuits = {
    'Monte Carlo': 7,
    'Shortbread Cream': 7,
    'Delta Cream': 6,
    'Kingston': 5
}

remaining = sum(biscuits.values())
while remaining:
    choice, *_ = choices(tuple(biscuits), weights=biscuits.values(), k=1)
    biscuits[choice] -= 1
    remaining = sum(biscuits.values())
    print('Choice:', choice, 'Remaining:', remaining)

print('No more left')
```